# Twitter API Login not redirecting approved users seamlessly

Tags: twitter, twitter-login

I've implemented sign in with Twitter such that users can log in and I store user's credentials. However, on their [tutorial page](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) it says:

> Signed in and approved: If the user is signed in on twitter.com and has already approved the calling application, they will be immediately authenticated and returned to the callback URL with a valid OAuth request token. The redirect to twitter.com is not obvious to the user.

In the diagram, my app never redirects transparently, it always asks users to grant access:

[image: From twitter's tutorial page]

Is there something I have to do to make my app redirect transparently? My website is over https if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: On their forum, there are others with [the same question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/authorize-to-use-your-account-keep-appearing/463) but it doesn't seem like any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the endpoint to http://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate instead of http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize